# How will I convert epoch timestamp to get hour of the day?

Tags: python, datetime, time

I am trying to identify a mathematical formula to convert the epoch timestamp in UTC and get the current hour of the day.

e.g., I have this timestamp in milliseconds `1528567668862`, which is:

```
GMT: Saturday, June 9, 2018 6:07:48.862 PM
Your time zone: Saturday, June 9, 2018 11:07:48.862 AM GMT-07:00 DST
```

I expect it to return me `6:07 PM`.